# R package installation in r studio

Tags: r

I have written a package for my personal use and my other colleagues. I have uploaded the files and source package to different websites. I am able to install the source package in my computer. But my colleagues cannot install it either by github.com (https://github.com/furqan915/Epi-gene) or by sourceforge.net (https://sourceforge.net/projects/epi-gene/). 
Common error is package cannot be installed and it does not add to user library.
I am unable to find out the problem.
Kindly help me out.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general programming. If you provide the errors you find and the steps you have done to find the cause of them it will be easier for people on Stack Overflow or other places to help you

Comment: The package installs without issues on my system. You’ll need to provide a lot more details about this error for people to be able to help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you use `devtools::install_github()` giving your github username/reposname

If not, you need to check that your R package is passing `R CMD check` or `devtools::check()`. See http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/check.html and http://kbroman.org/pkg_primer/pages/check.html for info

Comment: I have already finished running the RCMD check. I got 2 notes but it finished in good manner.

Answer (score 0):

A quick workaround is to install the package directly from source:

```
install.packages("~/Download/myPackage.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

You should be able to pass also `.zip` and URLs (other than CRAN).